# my queries are very slow when joined, separately they are fast

Tags: mysql

My both the queries separately work fast, but when I join both the queries it takes lots of time to execute,

```
SELECT b.*, 
       a.* 
FROM   (SELECT r.vou_no, 
               r.vou_date, 
               r.lr_date, 
               r.due_date, 
               r.vac_code, 
               r.vamount, 
               r.vmfg_amt, 
               r.vter_cd, 
               r.mkt_year, 
               r.mnth_code 
        FROM   ledfile AS r 
        WHERE  r.mkt_year = 2012 
               AND r.mnth_code BETWEEN 201210 AND 201306 
               AND r.div_code = 1 
               AND r.vdepo_code = 21 
               AND r.vbook_cd = 80 
               AND Ifnull(r.del_tag, '') <> 'D' 
        ORDER  BY r.vac_code, 
                  r.vou_date, 
                  r.vou_no) b, 
       (SELECT a.vac_code vcode, 
               a.vouno, 
               a.bill_date, 
               a.vamount  vamt, 
               a.vou_date vdate 
        FROM   rcpfile a 
        WHERE  a.mkt_year = 2012 
               AND a.div_code = 1 
               AND a.vdepo_code = 21 
               AND a.vbook_cd IN ( 20, 21, 22, 90, 
                                   98, 80 ) 
               AND Ifnull(a.del_tag, '') <> 'D' 
        ORDER  BY a.vac_code, 
                  a.bill_date, 
                  a.vouno) a 
WHERE  a.vcode = b.vac_code 
       AND a.vouno = b.vou_no 
       AND a.bill_date = b.vou_date;
```

Comment: can you please separate the sections

Comment: Explain what you are doing, don't just put a wall of code. And format it properly, please.

Comment: To perform a faster JOIN in a query on multiple tables, it is important to have the proper indexes on the tables. The columns being joined in the query must be in the indexes.

Comment: Is there any reason here to use subqueries rather then regular joins?

Comment: It would help to have an explain plan as well.

Comment: both the queries join on a.vcode = b.vac_code and a.vouno = b.vou_no and a.bill_date=b.vou_date. Should I create index on both the table i.s ledfile alias b and rcpfile alias a. @ DOK

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I have problem in running the above query it takes lots of time to execute please help.... @DMac

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
SELECT b.vou_no
     , b.vou_date
     , b.lr_date
     , b.due_date
     , b.vac_code
     , b.vamount
     , b.vmfg_amt
     , b.vter_cd
     , b.mkt_year
     , b.mnth_code
     , a.vac_code vcode 
     , a.vouno
     , a.bill_date
     , a.vamount vamt
     , a.vou_date vdate 
  FROM ledfile b 
  JOIN rcpfile a 
    ON a.mkt_year = b.mkt_year
   AND a.div_code = b.div_code
   AND a.vdepo_code = b.vdepo_code
   AND a.del_tag = b.del_tag
 WHERE a.vbook_cd IN (20,21,22,90,98,80) 
   AND COALESCE(b.del_tag,'') <> 'D' 
   AND b.mkt_year = 2012 
   AND b.mnth_code BETWEEN 201210 AND 201306 
   AND b.div_code = 1 
   AND b.vdepo_code = 21
   AND b.vbook_cd = 80
```

Comment: When I run this query Error Code : 2008
MySQL client ran out of memory @Strawberry